# How to get value of control programmaticaly created, before postback erase them ?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm creating some dynamic controls via code

```
'    fields is an array of string
    For Each field As String In fields
            If field.Trim <> "" Then
                fieldqty += 1

                Dim mylab As New Label
                mylab.Text = field
                mylab.ID = "lblInfo" & fieldqty 

                Dim mytxt As New TextBox
                mytxt.ID = "txtInfo" & fieldqty 

                panInfo.Controls.Add(mylab)
                panInfo.Controls.Add(mytxt)

            End If
  next 
  Session("FieldsQty") = fieldqty
```

Then, I've a button where I want to save or send via email content of that fields.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

         For k As Integer = 1 To CInt(Session("FieldsQty"))
                    Dim myTxt As TextBox
                    Dim myLbl As Label
                    lblMsg.Text = panInfo.Controls.Count 'Here I got 0 

                    myLbl = CType(panInfo.FindControl("lblInfo" & k), Label)  'HERE I get mylbl = Nothing
                    myTxt = CType(panInfo.FindControl("txtInfo" & k), TextBox) 'HERE I get myTxt = Nothing
       next k

    End Sub
```

It seems that just after i click the button controls disappear (not only their value: both value and controls).

I know that these controls are dinamically created, so they are not re-create after postback, but Just after I click the button they disappear and I can't neither save the value in it. Why ?

Thanks

**EDIT: Ok I've another question: How to get value of that control on button click?**

Comment: `"so they are not re-create after postback"` - Doesn't that answer your own question?  If they're not re-created after post-back then that's why they disappear.  They need to be re-created when handling the post-back.  Or am I misunderstanding something in the problem description?

Comment: Because they only exist until the next postback.  Asp.net will not recreate them for you.  You have to do it in Page_Load.